# Why C++ Boost Lib can't be used?

Tags: c++, boost

I recently started using the Boost Library and I am having problems with installing it.

What I did so far was:

- Download the lib , extracting it to "C:/Boost" Directory.
- Entering the Visual Studio 2012 CMD + did "cd C:/Boost/boost1_56_0".
- Typing the bootstrap.bat command and afterwards the b2 command.
- Entered Visual and added in the C/C++ General -> Additional Include Directories the directory of the boost root lib that I extracted earlier.
- In Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers, change Use Precompiled Header (/Yu) to Not Using Precompiled Headers

In that project I made a `main.cpp` file that contains:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

For some reason, and I don't have a clue any more, I get these errors:

1. LNK2019 - unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup
2. LNK1120 - 1 unresolved externals

I tried toying with the configurations and the commands from few places from the internet with no result. Why could this be happening?

Comment: It seems you didn't create a console project, so the main starting point isn't the `main` function, it's one called `WinMain`.

Comment: ***1.LNK2019 - unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup
2. LNK1120 - 1 unresolved externals*** You selected a windows application (not a console application) but do not have a WinMain.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new console project in visual studio and it should work for you.

The reason you get this error is you have created a windows application, and a windows applications entry point is called `WinMain`.

`main` is the entry point for console applications, which is correct in your situation.

Whereas the linker is looking for `WinMain` which causes an error as it can not find the entry point hence the unresolved external symbol.